# What does 'measured engagement' mean?

Tags: meaning

> As a son of refugees from the North, Moon is determined to go his own
>   way about it–tackling the Kim regime not by aggression but by
>   **measured engagement**. The current cycle of antagonism helps no one, he says, least of all the long-suffering population of the Hermit
>   Kingdom. “My father fled from the North, hating communism. I myself
>   hate the communist North Korean system. That doesn’t mean I should let
>   the people in the North suffer under an oppressive regime.” - Time(May
>   15, 2017 - Asia edition)

This is an excerpt from Time magazine, which is about Moon Jae-in, then a leading presidential candidate, now the President of South Korea.

Comment: *measured engagement* may mean here *steady and careful plan* [https://www.google.co.in/search?q=measured&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=dCodWeSHPJCBvATXm5GoBg]

Answer (score 2):

***[Measured](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/measured)*** in the sense of:

> slow, careful, and deliberate:
>
> - We are taking a careful and measured approach to the problem.

Macmillan Dictionary

The article says that President  Moon will adopt a very careful attitude towards Kim regime (probably to avoid possible conflicts),